# sample command in teradata uniform

Tags: teradata

Just wondering, does SAMPLE in teradata select with a uniform probability (i.e. gives every row the same probability to be selected). Example:

```
select * from employee_table sample 8;
```

Also will the returned data be guaranteed to be different after each execution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each `SAMPLE` is random, but using the defaults not a true simple sample. All AMPs communicate to decide how many rows will be returned by which AMP, i.e. the default `SAMPLE` is a `UNION` of n seperate samples, one per AMP. It's hard to notice because the data is hash distributed, but a skewed table with a NUPI might have a higher probability for some rows to be sampled.

When you need a true random sample you have to use the `SAMPLE RANDOMIZED ALLOCATION` option, now all rows across all AMPs have the same probability.

But as it's random, of course it's not guaranteed to have different rows within each sample.